# Is there a limit to the number of employee levels I can have in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

My question is how far vertically can I extend my netsuite hierarchy?
For further clarification, if Employee A is a Janitor, Employee B is Janitorial supervisor, Employee C is Head of Janitorial Services etc. how many levels can I create in NetSuite before I run into some sort of limit?

etc.
C
B
A

Comment: the etc. C B A should be vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlimited, you can create as many as you want. I can't find any information about the restriction from NetSuite's help guide. But in reality I can't think of a scenario wherein you will have more than 100 unless there's a company of 1000 strong and each of the employee is reporting to another employee on top or the company is big as Coca Cola with more than 100k employees.